# Will a React component re-render if its props are updated, but don't change in value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

Let's say we've got a redux store that looks like this:

```
{
  "page1": {
    "title": "Demo",
    "content": "Testing"
  },
  "page2": {
    "title": "Demo",
    "content": "Yes, I'm aware the titles match."
  }
}
```

Now let's look at the component that renders the title:

```
const Title = ({title}) => <h1>{title}</h1>

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  title: getCurrentPage().title
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Title)
```

In the above block, getCurrentPage() is a memoized function (via reselect) that derives the current page data from the state based on some condition (in this case, it's react-router's location.pathname).

Will this component re-render when the data returned by getCurrentPage() is different, even though the specific value of {title} stays the same?

If yes, will memoizing the derived title prop change the answer to no?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I took the time to test out my own question because the first answer I received said it would re-render. I inserted console.log('render') into the Title component and then navigated between two separate pages that each shared the same exact title. And the result... (drum roll)

**NO**. The component did not re-render.

Answer (score 1):

The component will re-render if the props changed, or the local state changed due to a call to `setState()`, or you explicitly call the `foceUpdate()` function. In your case, the title is a string, and the old string and new string have the same value, so, there is no change in the props, therefore no re-render.

One thing to be careful is passing an object to a props. react won't do a deep comparison, so the result may be different from your expectation. In that case, you need to compare the old and new objects by yourself in the `getDerivedStateFromProps` or `componentWillRecieveProps` in old versions, and then decide whether you need to call `forceUpdate()` to force the component to re-render.

Answer (score 0):

in my tests not with redux and object it does and i had add a check comand to my compoments for only updating when real change.

Btw why not test with a simple console.log?

Comment: I finally ran a test myself with the specific conditions (redux, reselect, react router) mentioned above and the component did not re-render. I don't know how you set up your test, but without redux, I assume it must have depended on props passed down from a parent component. That may account for the different results.

Comment: Curious if case @StefanBD mentions was perhaps with object props rather than scalar-type props like your string title example. React likely uses `===` (for objects, simple reference checks) in that case.

Comment: yap Will Cain is correct, i used object {a:1, b:2, c:3} and updatet one value in the object so react rerendert everything for me which ends in a massive performance dissaster and i had to cheat with the compoment should update function